# Add element to a string

Tags: java

I use java and I have the following string:

```
 points="335,234 285,320 185,320 135,234 186,147 285,147 335,233 ";
```

How it is possible to add 2 to each number?...for example:

```
points="337,236 287,322 187,322 137,236 188,149 287,149 337,235 ";
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it appears to be a zero-effort requirements dump.  If you can [edit] your question to show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, or to clarify *precisely* where you are having difficulty, this downvote may be retracted.

Comment: They're strings.  Not numbers.  They may look like numbers, but they're not represented by a numeral data type.  Here's the hint:  if you want to represent them as such, you'll need to split your string, convert everything that's number-like to a number, and *then* perform your math.

Comment: If you need to do math operations, why are they in a string in the first place instead of using actual numbers in an array? Strings are not numbers, they're strings. Use the proper type for the purpose, instead of trying to kludge your way around self-inflicted damage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move polygon in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47779268/move-polygon-in-java) ... specifically, a poor rephrasing of the same question by the OP.

Comment: @AJNeufeld:  ...what??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String#split` to get all the separate numbers in an array, then use a `for` to iterate through them:

```
    String points = "335,234,285,320,185,320,135,234,186,147,285,147,335,233";
    String[] indvPoints = points.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < indvPoints.length; i++) {
        indvPoints[i] = String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(indvPoints[i]) + 2);
    }

    points = Arrays.toString(indvPoints).replaceAll("[\\[\\] ]", "");
    System.out.println(points);
```

Although I suggest you just use an `int` array to begin with, it would be much more efficient and less likely to encounter errors:

```
    int[] points = {335,234,285,320,185,320,135,234,186,147,285,147,335,233};

    for(int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i] += 2;
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(points));
```